# Common elements between two randomly formed java arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Frame of the question:
Write a class called CommonElements with a single method main that will:

Create and obtain two integer arrays (arrayA and arrayB) using RandomIntegerArrayCreator type objects and its methods,
find the number of common elements between arrayA and arrayB (say: if integer 2 appears in arrayA once and twice in arrayB, that counts as ONE common element between the two),

Constraints / notes:
All array elements are integers from the the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} and can appear multiple times in each array,
Arrays A and B do NOT have to be of the same size,
Arrays A and B CAN be empty (no elements),
Arrays A and B will NOT be sorted.

The code that I have already created:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomIntegerArrayCreator {
    int[] arr;

    RandomIntegerArrayCreator(){
        Random rand = new Random();

        int size = rand.nextInt(16);
        arr = new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

            arr[i] = rand.nextInt(11);
        }
    }
    public int getArraySize(){
        return this.arr.length;
    }
    public int[] getArray(){
        return this.arr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomIntegerArrayCreator r = new RandomIntegerArrayCreator();
        System.out.println("Size = "+r.getArraySize());
        int[] arr = r.getArray();
        System.out.print("Generated array is ");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Where is your problem and how can we assist you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pseudo code for what you're looking for.

```
for i=0, i<size arrayA
  for j=0, j<size arrayB
     if arrayA[i] == arrayB[j]
        if(arrayA is not in dummyarray)
            dummyarray.append(arrayA[i])
            counter++
```

Edit: Basically, you iterate through arrayA and go through each element in arrayB and check if there's something that matches (For instance, arrayA[3] = 4 and arrayB[2] = 4, then there's a match). You add the number to a dummy list which you can check later to see if there's been a duplicate match.